# Convert rnorm output of NumericVector with length of 1 to a double?

Tags: type-conversion, rcpp

In the following code I am trying to generate a `NumericVector` of values from a normal distribution, where every time `rnorm()` is called each time with a different mean and variance.

Here is the code:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector generate_ai(NumericVector log_var) {

  int log_var_length = log_var.size();

  NumericVector temp(log_var_length);

  for(int i = 0; i < log_var_length; i++) {
    temp[i] = rnorm(1, -0.5 * log_var[i], sqrt(log_var[i]));
  }

  return(temp);
}
```

The line that is giving me trouble is this one:

```
temp[i] = rnorm(1, -0.5 * log_var[i], sqrt(log_var[i]));
```

It is causing the error:

> assigning to 'typename storage_type<14>::type' (aka 'double') from
>   incompatible type 'NumericVector' (aka 'Vector<14>')

Since I'm returning one number from `rnorm`, is there a way to convert this `NumericVector` return type to a `double`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rcpp provides two methods to access RNG sampling schemes. The first option is a single draw and the second enables `n` draws using some sweet sweet [Rcpp sugar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-sugar.pdf). Under your current setup, you are opting for the later setup.

**Option 1.** Use just the scalar sampling scheme instead of sugar by accessing the RNG function through `R::`, e.g.

```
temp[i] = R::rnorm(-0.5 * log_var[i], sqrt(log_var[i]));
```

**Option 2.** Use the subset operator on the `NumericVector` to obtain the only element.

```
// C++ indices start at 0 instead of 1
temp[i] = Rcpp::rnorm(1, -0.5 * log_var[i], sqrt(log_var[i]))[0];
```

The prior option will be faster and better. Why you might ask?

Well, **Option 2** creates a new `NumericVector`, fills it with a call to **Option 1**, then requires a subset operation to retrieve the value *before* assigning it to the desired scalar.

In any case, RNG can be a bit confusing. Just make sure to always prefix the function call with the correct namespace (e.g. `R::` or `Rcpp::`) so that you and perhaps future programmers avoid any ambiguity as to what kind of sampling scheme you've opted for.

(This is one of the downside of `using namespace Rcpp;`)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you the insight. I actually figured out your Option 2, but the  Option 1 is giving me some ideas for other parts of my code! I am curious though, why do you say the first option will be faster ?

Comment: **Option 2** creates a new `NumericVector`, fills it with a call to **Option 1**, then requires a subset operation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Could you tell me why your Option 1 rnorm only has two arguments? Why is there no 1 in the first argument? As well, could you point me in the direction of a good resource for using R:: ?